# No value for videoId in json

Tags: java, android, json

I'm working in a project that get videos from youtube using json. 2 days ago this method

```
private void showVideo() {
    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject jsonVideoId = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("id");
                    JSONObject jsonsnippet = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("snippet");
                    JSONObject jsonObjectdefault = jsonsnippet.getJSONObject("thumbnails").getJSONObject("medium");

                    VideoDetails videoDetails = new VideoDetails();

                    String videoid = jsonVideoId.getString("videoId");

                    Log.e(TAG," New Video Id " + videoid);
                    videoDetails.setURL(jsonObjectdefault.getString("url"));
                    videoDetails.setVideoName(jsonsnippet.getString("title"));

                    videoDetailsArrayList.add(videoDetails);
                }
                lvVideo.setAdapter(customListAdapter);
                customListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    int socketTimeout = 30000;
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

was working fine but now it doesn't. I found some questions here on stackoverflow but none of them solved my problem. I tried to change

```
JSONObject jsonVideoId = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("id");
String videoid = jsonVideoId.getString("videoId");
```

to

```
String videoid = (String) ((JSONObject) ((JSONObject) jsonObject1.getJSONArray("items").get(0)).get("id")).get("videoId");
```

these change show the videos but when I click in some video just open the first one (I know that happens because the .get(0) but when I change to .get(i) I receive a message wiht the error

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for videoId
```

EDIT:
The data from Youtube:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"******"",
 "nextPageToken": "******",
 "regionCode": "BR",
 "pageInfo": {
 "totalResults": 76,
 "resultsPerPage": 50
 },
 "items": [
  {
  "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
  "etag": "\"*****"",
  id": {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "videoId": "****"
  },
```

Comment: Can you provide json example?

Comment: @Iske I edited the question with the youtube data. The videoId is under the id but I don't understand why the code work just some days and then stop.

Comment: The Log.e provide all the videos Id.

Comment: I would suggest implementing some logging and after that checking what response your application failed to parse... You could log response when JSONException is caught.

Comment: I solved, @Iske. I just added if (JSONObject.has("valueId")) { code }. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Great mate! It would be good to add else statement with some logging to get noticed when is is missing...